# How change urlpatterns path in urls.py in function of argument passed to manage.py?

Tags: django, python-3.x

i want change in urls.py:

urlpatterns = [path('rmt/{}'.format(url), view)]

from argument passed to manage.py

```
class InitializeService():
    def __init__(self):
        os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'RMT_Django.settings')
        try:
            from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
        except ImportError as exc:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            ) from exc

            flag_env = sys.argv[6]
            if flag_env == "DEV":
                url = "/rmt/push_dev"
            elif flag_env == "TEST":
                url = "/rmt/push_test"
            elif flag_env == "PROD":
                url = "/rmt/push"

        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv[0:3])

InitializeService()
```

how pass url to urlpattern?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not the right way to do this.

## Way 1: Doing it in `views.py`

```py
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('rmt/<str:service_url>/'.format(url), handeller_view)
]
```

```py
# views.py

flag_env = sys.argv[6]
service_mapping = {'DEV': 'push_dev', 'TEST': 'push_test', 'PROD': 'push'}

def handeller_view(request, service_url):
    if service_url == service_mapping[flag_env]:
        # handel your request accordingly

    raise Http404()
```

## Way 2: Doing it in `urls.py`

Alternatively what you can do is match URLs on the basis on the `args`.

```py
# urls.py

flag_env = sys.argv[6]
if flag_env == "DEV":
   url = "/rmt/push_dev"
elif flag_env == "TEST":
   url = "/rmt/push_test"
elif flag_env == "PROD":
   url = "/rmt/push"


urlpatterns = [
   path(url, view),
]
```

Or you can create a URL pattern on the basis of your flag, this will be useful if there is more than one url in according to your flag.

```py
# urls.py

flag_env = sys.argv[6]
if flag_env == "DEV":
   urlpatterns = [
        path("/rmt/push_dev", view),
    ]
elif flag_env == "TEST":
   urlpatterns = [
        path("/rmt/push_test", view),
    ]

elif flag_env == "PROD":
   urlpatterns = [
        path("/rmt/push", view),
    ]
```

Comment: i need remove urls.py?

Comment: Nope, that urlpatterns is in urls.py as before.

Comment: but i no need this.. I need runserver on different endpoint if argv is DEV,TEST or PROD before! no after